# Spark Streaming Kafka - How to stop streaming after processing all existing messages (gracefully)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka

This is what i am trying to do

Stream data from a kafka topic, which keeps getting data continuously. 
Run the job twice a day, to process all data existing data at that point and stop the stream.

So i put and call stop on the query initially, but it was throwing "TimeoutException"

Then i tried increasing the timeout dynamically, but now i am getting java.io.IOException: Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException

So, is there any way to gracefully stop the stream without getting any exceptions?

Below is my current code (part), which is throwing the interrupted exception

```
df = (
    spark.readStream.format("kafka")
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", os.environ["KAFKA_SERVERS"])
    .option("subscribe", config.kafka.topic)
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
    .option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 25000)
    .load()
)


#   <do some processing and save the data>
def save_batch(batch_df, batch_id):
    pass

query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(save_batch).start(
    outputMode="append",
    checkpointLocation=os.path.join(checkpoint_path, config.kafka.topic),
)

while query.isActive:
    progress = query.lastProgress
    if progress and progress["numInputRows"] < 25000 * 0.9:
        timeout = sum(progress["durationMs"].values())
        timeout = min(5 * 60 * 1000, max(15000, timeout))
        spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.stopTimeout", str(timeout))
        stream_query.stop()
        break
    time.sleep(10)
```

Spark Version: 2.4.5
Scala Version: 2.1.1

Comment: its still throwing InterruptedException even after setting the specified config to true

Comment: Have you considered having a simpler spark batch job instead of a streaming job and schedule it twice a day? This use case does not sound to fit with streaming to me.

Comment: the kafka topic gets populated with huge amount of data, and the spark streaming takes care of the checkpoint and offsets headache, which i assume i have to manage if try doing some batch job, which doesn't make it simple. let me know if my assumption is wrong

Comment: I agree with @mike. If you really want to do it this way, I'd use [Accumulator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Accumulator) to track the timestamp of the last active batch, then in `isActive` get back the timestamp, if timestamp > limit, gracefully shutdown

Comment: once again how to shutdown gracefully, the `query.stop()` is throwing either TimeoutException or InterruptedException

Answer (score 4):

Update: With Spark 3.3 `.trigger(availableNow=True)` is an option that will play nicely with `.option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 25000)`.

I would recommend `.trigger(once=True)` and `.awaitTermination()` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#triggers).

*Warning*: This will not work with `.option("maxOffsetsPerTrigger", 25000)`, but if `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` is not set it will default to pulling all offsets since it was last run to create one large micro-batch.

```py
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", os.environ["KAFKA_SERVERS"]) \
    .option("subscribe", config.kafka.topic) \
    .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
    .load()

def foreach_batch_function(df, epoch_id):
    # Transform and write batchDF
    pass

df \
    .writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(foreach_batch_function) \
    .trigger(once=True) \
    .start(
        outputMode="append",
        checkpointLocation=os.path.join(checkpoint_path, config.kafka.topic),
    ) \
    .awaitTermination()
```